# How to restart jenkins running on the windows machine

Tags: jenkins

Am running jenkins on my windows 10 machine through jenkins.war by running the below command from cmd

java -jar jenkins.war --httpPost=8047

when i try to restart jenkins through UI, am not able to do it getting the exception "Jenkins cannot restart itself as currently configured."

This is the commands i have tried so far by restarting.

http://localhost:8090/restart and i tried with one more url as well

http://localhost:8090/safeRestart

Kindly advise if am missing anything here.

Answer (score 1):

Please change your port URL. You have started jenkins on 8047 and you are using port 8090.

You can use http://localhost:8047/restart

Answer (score 0):

Try to open your console, go to your Jenkins directory and type: **jenkins.exe restart**

Comment: I have used the jenkins.war in the windows not through the exe.